# How can I use an Outlet Collection with labels and buttons in one collection?

Tags: swift, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I am trying to make an Outlet collection that consists of labels and buttons. I was thinking I could just do something like `@IBOutlet var basicCollection: [Any]!` this doesn't seem to work. Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@IBOutlet var basicCollection: [UIView]!
```

Works for me.