# attach several UILabels from storyboard to one IBOutlet

Tags: swift, uikit

I've 15 Labels in my `Storyboard` they are just texts, also set from storyboard, What I want to do is to style them, but programitically, Therefore I need to create 15 `IBOutlets` in my `ViewController`, I wonder if there is any other way of doing that, without 15 `IBOutlets`,if it's possible to create 1 IBOutlet and attach all of them to that one? because creating 15 of them is kinda stressing...

Comment: You could tell your view to give you a list of its subviews and then inspect each to see if it was a label you wanted to adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Outlet Collections instead of an IBOutlet for all the labels you want to group together:

What I like to do is to create the specific outlet collection in code first if I way to track the same type like so:

`@IBOutlet var labelCollection: [UILabel]!`

The I drag from the editor to the storyboard

[image: IBOutlet Collection XCode multiple UIViews UILabels]

Then I can work with it as follows

```
@IBOutlet var labelCollection: [UILabel]!

func setCustomLayout()
{
    for label in labelCollection
    {
        // do your customization here
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through the UIViews inside the IBOutletCollection and do the needful

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292457/1619193), it seems like you could also have multiple types in a single outlet collection.

Comment: Your version works totally fine, but I've read a long time ago about that, some people say that it's not recommended to do it this way, any idea about that opinion?

Comment: I can't really say what their reason was. The only one I can think of is that if you want to connect multiple views to IBOutlets of different types, you cannot do it the second way. So for example if you want to apply the same text color to buttons, textfields and labels - you can only do it the first way.